# Does ChildView can setSaturation value bigger than Parent?

Tags: android

I have a layout ，a ImageView In a FrameLayout ,the ImageView‘s origin color is red.First I make the FrameLayout to be gray.the Code like below:

```
public GrayFramLayout(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();
        cm.setSaturation(0);
        mPaint.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm));
    }

    public GrayFramLayout(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.saveLayer(null, mPaint, Canvas.ALL_SAVE_FLAG);
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
        //canvas.save();

    }

   @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
  if(ivTest != null) {
    ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();
    cm.setSaturation(1);
    mPaint.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm));
   ivTest.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, mPaint);

   }
}
```

after run the app ,ImageView to be gray, then I click the ImageView,call the code up,but the ImageView can not tobe the origin red color  !!  Anyone can help me ?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please edit the last sentence to make clear what *is* or *isn't* happening and what you need.

Comment: The ParentView  setSaturation(0) to make the childView gray. Then the childView  
 setSaturation(1) want tobe normal dispaly, but the childvew still be gray

Comment: @Juul    The ParentView setSaturation(0) to make the childView gray. Then the childView setSaturation(1) want tobe normal dispaly, but the childView still be gray